# TortoiseSVN - Trac - TracExplorer HELL

Tags: tortoisesvn, trac

All,
I want to integrate TortoiseSVN with Edgewall's Trac via the TracExplorer plugin. I am working with Windows.

What I did:

1. I installed Trac 1.0.10.
2. Trac is running under http:127.0.0.1/trac
3. I installed TortoiseSVN Version 1.8
4. In the Tortoise repo browser I added my source code folder under Trunk and checked it out.
5. I downloaded and installed the TracExplorer 0.2.0-beta msi installer.
6. On the source code directory I right-clicked and selected TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Hook Scripts -> Issue Tracker Integration
7. I press Add...
8. I enter the Working Copy Path to my source code Directory
9. I select the Provider "TracExplorer.TSVNTrac.TracProvider"
10. I am taken to select or add a new Trac Provider.

This is where hell begins:

11. I enter for Trac URL: http://127.0.0.1/trac with "Basic authentication" (my credentials, which work perfectly under that URL when actually using Trac)

The result is: Server Check failed. Not found!
I play around with authentication method and URL depth, no luck.

Selecting "No authentication" or "Integrated authentication" - whatever this means - brings about the message: Unauthorized. Regardless of the URL.

What is wrong?

Comment: I found a forum dedicated to this topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tracexplorer will look here too. Reading through the posts my issue seems to be related to not having installed XML-RPC.

Comment: TracExplorer may not be under active development, so that's something to watch out for. I used it more than 8 years back and it worked fine at the time. I think you are [right about needing XmlRpcPlugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tracexplorer/wikis/Documentation.wiki).